# Boolean is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

I'm just trying to figure out why this code isn't working.

```
var programming = false;
var happy = function() {
  if(programming === true) {
      happy = false;
  }
  else {
      happy = true
  }
};
```

or my secondary code

```
var programming = false;
var happy = function() {
  if(programming === true) {
      happy = false;
  }
  if(programming) {
      happy = true;
  }
  };
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? What is actually happening? What exactly does "isn't working" mean?

Comment: Why are you assigning a boolean to happy if you don't want it to be a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
var programming = false;
var happy = function() {
  if(programming === true) {
      return false;
  }
  else {
      return true;
  }
};
```

This is how javascript works. You set the return value of a function using the keyword `return`, not by reassigning the function to it's return value.

What happens with your code is that the first time the function is called, it replaces itself by it's return value (that is a boolean). The second time you try to call it, the function doesn't exist anymore, because the variable `happy` now contains a boolean (the result of the first time you called it).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code and the error message,

```
var happy = function() {
  if(programming === true) {
      happy = false;
  }
  else {
      happy = true
  }
};
```

you have a function called `happy` but then you are overriding it with a boolean and it seems like you are calling it later which yields the error "Boolean is not a function". Change the variable `happy` inside the function to a different name.

---

One interesting thing in JavaScript is that if you change the way you declare your function, you code will not throw an error:

```
var programming = false;
function happy() {
    if(programming === true) {
        happy = false;          //you should use the keyword var here actually
    } else {
        happy = true;
    }
}
happy();
```

This will not change the function to a boolean: http://jsfiddle.net/kLksY/

Comment: "seems like"? The code you quoted is defining the function named `happy`. Then you call it, it redefines itself as the boolean.

Comment: @Barmar - I used the word "seems like" because the code posted in the question doesn't show the function is called.

Comment: "seems like" was applied to "you have", not "you call". And it's obvious that he was calling it, because that's the only way to get the error.